# Add cell to an Array using data from a UIPickerView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, uipickerview, nsinteger

I have a UIPickerView with three components, and each component has NSIntegerMax for the numbers.  So, I just need to get the data from each component, and send it to another ViewController called, CreationViewController.  The three objects I need to send are strings, set up like so:

```
NSInteger supplyData = [supplypick selectedRowInComponent:0];
NSInteger mineralData = [supplypick selectedRowInComponent:1];
NSInteger vespeneData = [supplypick selectedRowInComponent:2];
```

So, I would like to add each cell in the format of this log:

```
  NSLog(@"%i  %@  M:%i  G:%i", supplyData, namer.text, mineralData, vespeneData);
```

All I need to know it what to put...

```
 NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [array addObject:        ];
                  ^^HERE^^
```

This is all in one function.  Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
[array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i  %@  M:%i  G:%i", supplyData, namer.text, mineralData, vespeneData]];
```

Comment: It looks great, but I want to add it to a plist with strings, called CreationArray.plist.  How could I do that?

Comment: Just write your array to the file using -writeToFile:atomically: This will generate a plist with some default format. Use NSPropertyListSerialization if you need more control over the output.

Comment: Actually, I want to add it to another array in a different class.  I've imported the class, but I don't know what to do after the equals sign, like, CreationViewController * creation =...  How could I do that?  Thanks for your help.